# Calculating Area Under Individual Peaks in Python After FFT

Tags: python, math, numpy, matplotlib, fft

I've generated a graph of a FFT, with a number of individual peaks, in Python 2.7.3.

[image: http://imgur.com/O9E0e]

I understand that to calculate the area under the whole graph, I can either sum the values or use trapz, but I'm struggling when trying to restrict these calculations to a single region. For example, I'd like to calculate just the area between 105 and 120Hz, or between 145 and 155Hz.

If it helps, the code to generate this graph is:

```
x=arange(0,15,0.01)

y=exp(-0.3*x)*exp(x*pi*20j)+exp(-0.9*x)*exp(x*pi*25j)+exp(-0.9*x)*exp(x*pi*15j)

fft(y)
plot(fft(y))
xlabel('frequency (Hz)')
show()
```

I'm sure I'm probably just missing something relatively simple, but as a complete novice of programming I'd appreciate any help you can provide and a brief search of SO didn't provide any answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a simple sum (or trapezoidal) integration:

```
ft = np.fft.fft(y)
integral = sum(ft[105:121])
```

or

```
integral = np.trapz(ft[105:121])
```

seems like it should work.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = x=np.arange(0,15,0.01)
>>> from numpy import exp,pi
>>> y=exp(-0.3*x)*exp(x*pi*20j)+exp(-0.9*x)*exp(x*pi*25j)+exp(-0.9*x)*exp(x*pi*15j)
>>> ft = np.fft.fft(y)
>>> np.trapz(ft[105:121])
(642.14009362811771+142.9776425340925j)
>>> sum(ft[105:121])
(652.29308789751224+152.70583448308713j)
```

Comment: That's absolutely the kind of answer I was hoping for, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

An integral of an exponential, $\int_a^{b} \exp(x*q)  = (1/q)*(\exp(b*q) - \exp(a*q))$

Comment: But, once transformed to frequency space, you're integrating the fourier transform of an exponential ...

Comment: Yes. In the integral of `f(x)` from `a` to `b` write `f(x)` as an integral over the fourier space of its FT, then change the order of integrations. What's left is the integral over the fourier space of the FT of the function times the integral of an exponential, which gives something like `sin(kx)/kx`